AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon

Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

While updating the compileSdkVersion as 34 and targetSdkVersion as 34 and minSdkVersion as 22 the above error is showing. Here I have mentioned the versions.
Gardle - 8.7
Node - 16.17.0
cordova - 12.0.0
I have try changing the compileSdkVersion as 34 and targetSdkVersion as 34 and minSdkVersion as 22 in config.xml and updated the gradle version from 7.3.3 to 8.7

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@gokul, I am encountering the same issue and I am using com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2, and I get the same error :  AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
